# Make "less" jump point to center of search result rather than top

Tags: less

If one searches in `less` by typing `/search term` and jumping to search results with <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> the view of the text jumps so that the occurrence of the search term is at top of the terminal. Displaying the half of text before and after the occurrence is much more useful and I'd like to know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `-j` option. For instance, if you use `less -j3`, the match will be displayed on the 3rd line. To do what you want, i.e. display the match at the center of the terminal:

```
less -j$((LINES/2))
```

or since less 397, one can specify a percentage within the screen:

```
less -j.5
```

Note: To do that permanently, i.e. for all invocations, you can put this `-j`*n* option in the `LESS` environment variable.

This also affects commands to go to line *N*, e.g. line *N* will appear on the 3rd line of the terminal with `-j3`. A minor drawback is that one can get [spurious empty lines before the beginning of the file](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=763631), e.g. with the key <kbd><</kbd>. **EDIT:** I've written a [patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=763631;filename=less-goline.patch;msg=35) to avoid this problem; see [this message](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=763631#35) of my bug report for additional details. This patch allows one to avoid these empty lines only when going to the special line 0, which is the default for keys `g` and `<`. Thus it should be sufficient in practice.

Comment: Great! Works in `man` with `LESS` variable, e.g. `LESS="-j3" man <program>`, BTW.

Comment: @vinc17 By the way, I tried to do it permanently by putting `-j.5` in my `.lessrc` file but it doesn't work that way. OTOH, it work by setting the `LESS=-j.5`. Why it doesn't work in the `.lessrc` method?

Comment: @Utku The `less(1)` man page does not mention a `.lessrc` file.

Comment: This option (as any other) can also be set in a running session by typing `-j` and a number (Less will request the number with prompt `Target line:`).

Comment: Is there any way to solve the "spurious empty lines before the beginning of the file" problem?

Comment: @AleXoundOS I've just written a patch to avoid this spurious empty lines problem. It is available in my Debian bug report at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=763631#10

Comment: @AleXoundOS I've written a new patch, which avoids the issue with long lines. It works only when going to the special line 0, which is the default for keys `g` and `<`, so that it should be sufficient in practice. See my edited answer above. I've also created a pull request upstream: https://github.com/gwsw/less/pull/94 (and https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/93 is the associated bug).